# PXE boot 14.04 : filesystem.dir not working: do I have to use filesystem.squashfs?

Tags: boot, upstart

I've been using PXE-Boot with an extracted filesystem rather than `squashfs` so far:

```
[NFS-server]:/[cdpath]/casper/filesystem.dir/
```

instead of

```
[NFS-server]:/[cdpath]/casper/filesystem.squashfs
```

This option does not work for me on 14.04.1 any longer. It is still mentioned in 
`initrd:/scripts/casper` but system freezes during upstart after having done NFS chroot.

Did I miss something ?

With squashfs everything is OK but this leads to long turnaround times and `/var/log/messages`:

```
SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0xXXXX" on longer uptimes
```